# abp.io - How to user IRemoteStreamContent with BLOB Storing Azure Provider?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage, abp

**Documentation**

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Blob-Storing-Azure

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Application-Services#working-with-streams

**Issue**

Return empty response

*Note - But works with FileSteam*

**Steps needed to reproduce the problem.**

ABP Framework version 3.3.2.

```
public async Task<IRemoteStreamContent> DownloadAsync(string path)
{
    if (path == null) return await Task.FromResult(
        (IRemoteStreamContent)new RemoteStreamContent(new MemoryStream()));

    var fs = await blobContainer.GetAsync(path);

    var result = new RemoteStreamContent(fs)
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```

Comment: hi This is a duplicate with https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/7418

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task<IRemoteStreamContent> DownloadAsync(string path)
{
    if (path == null) return await Task.FromResult(
        (IRemoteStreamContent)new RemoteStreamContent(new MemoryStream()));

    var fs = await blobContainer.GetAsync(path);
    fs.Position = 0;
    
    var result = (IRemoteStreamContent) new RemoteStreamContent(fs)
    {
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    };

    return await Task.FromResult(result);
}
```